# Finding input and button elements with sellinium

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm able to enter this page [here](https://www.spribe.co/games/aviator) and click confirm cookies "Got it" button, click "play demo" button and click confirm age button to enter this page [here](https://aviator-next.spribegaming.com/?user=1180421&token=3152cf089ba8b4c2d08591154848e680a0f299e6462199ea6b9aa6de3613dbb2%E2%8C%A9=EN&currency=USD&return_url=https://spribe.co/games&operator=demo) (TOKEN CREATED FOR EACH DEMO FOR THIS LINK)

I'm also able to extract the value from the round count using this xpath here @class,'coefficient and also extract the finished round count value using this xpath here @class,'flew-coefficient

What I want to do next is to locate the input element and enter the value amount on the left hand side and click the big blue "bet" button on the left hand side but I can't seem to locate the value input "1.00" and the button on the left of the page. Please see my code and assist if you can.

Comment: Did my answer resolve your problem?

Comment: In a way it did with the input but I had to find the correct input element which I did but I can only delete one input text value. Also I can locate the button but it is not clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the desired input value please try this:

```java
String inputXpath = "//input[contains(@class,'roboto-font-b')]";
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.xpath(inputXpath));
input.click();
input.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a",Keys.DELETE));
input.sendKeys("20");
```

To click the Bet button please try this:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'success')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to come back this late, I had some personal stuff to attend.

I managed to use the following xpath to find the input but only one text is deleted:

```
String inputXpathL = "//app-bet-control[@class='bet-control double-bet'] //div[@class='second row']//input[@class='roboto-font-b']"; WebElement inputTargetL = driver.findElement(By.xpath(inputXpathL)); inputTargetL.click(); inputTargetL.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a",Keys.DELETE)); inputTargetL.sendKeys("10");
```

For the button I used the following xpath but the button is unclickable and there are no exceptions or errors:

```
findElement(By.xpath("//app-bet-control[@class='bet-control double-bet']//button[@class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm betopt ng-star-inserted']")).click();
```